# How to communicate between two fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to create an Android app that will have two fragments. One containing a list of various cities and the other containing details about these cities. I'm new at mobile dev and am having a hard time figuring out how to communicate between them. So far I have the list of cities stored in a fragment but still need to figure out how to show the description when one of the list items is clicked. Also I'm not sure where the descriptions would even be stored or how to access it. Any help would be great thank you.

cityDetails file:

```
public class cityDetails extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public cityDetails() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment cityDetails.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static cityDetails newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        cityDetails fragment = new cityDetails();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_city_details, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

cityListFragment file:

```
public class citiesFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Customize parameter argument names
    private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
    // TODO: Customize parameters
    private int mColumnCount = 1;
    private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public citiesFragment() {
    }

    // TODO: Customize parameter initialization
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static citiesFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
        citiesFragment fragment = new citiesFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cities_list, container, false);

        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();

            String[] cities = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Cities);
            List<DummyItem> mValues = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
                mValues.add(new DummyItem(String.valueOf(i + 1), cities[i], ""));
            }

            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
            }

            recyclerView.setAdapter(new MycitiesRecyclerViewAdapter(mValues, mListener));
        }

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onListFragmentInteraction(DummyItem item);
    }
}
```

mainActivity file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements citiesFragment.OnListFragmentInteractionListener, cityDetails.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListFragmentInteraction(DummyContent.DummyItem item) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are billiant videos by CodingInFlow who explained how to with an example

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACK67xU1Y3s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i22INe14JUc

Answer (score 0):

2 Parts to the question:

1. How to communicate between fragments
2. How to store the data for the details

For the first problem, the cleanest solution is creating an interface https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating. Basically, having a listener in one fragment which notifies the other fragment of an update.
Or in simpler terms without going into all this, for a short term solution, create an update function or something similar in your details fragment. So when the user selects a city in the list fragment, you just call the update function passing in the city name as key.

For the second problem. The short solution would be to create a hash map, where keys are the city names and values are the details. So when the details fragment gets the city name, it can look up the details easily. You can continue to complicate this as your needs change, like saving the data in a separate file and loading it, have a local key-value database, or even have a database on a cloud-like Firebase or AWS to update data on the fly.

Comment: How would I create that method? I've been trying now for a while and can't seem to get it right. I was trying to create a textview equal to the id of the textview inside the fragment and then use if else statements to set the text but that isn't working and im not sure how you would know which item in the list is being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

1 .With the help of ViewModel

The ViewModel process is very simple and you can learn how to communicate between Fragments using ViewModel by reading our Shared ViewModel blog at MindOrks.

https://blog.mindorks.com/shared-viewmodel-in-android-shared-between-fragments

2 .With the help of Interface

Make an Interface in your FragmentA

Implement the Interface of the FragmentA in your Activity

Call the Interface method from your Activity

In your Activity, call your FragmentB to do the required changes